# Making staggered fade in and out loop for multiple elements with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make a fade in and out animation for multiple elements using jquery. It's pretty hard to explain so I will put in the relevant code first.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#1").delay(0).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 1000);
      $("#2").delay(1000).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 1000);
      $("#3").delay(2000).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 1000);
      $("#4").delay(3000).animate({
        'opacity': '1'
      }, 1000);
    });
```

```css
.hideme {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="1" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What this code currently does is have each of the four parent divs in the container fade in one by one. What I want is, afterwards, for the all the divs with the class "first" to fade out at the same time, then each of those "first" divs to fade in one by one (like all the parent divs did on loading but only the "first" divs), have the divs fade out again at the same time again, and loop this indefinitely. That means that the "first" divs will fade in and out, but the "second" divs will remain on screen constantly after the first fade-in. Keep in mind that the "first" divs should not fade in simultaneously, but one after another. I'm having trouble figuring out how to write this code.

Comment: IDs **must** be unique

Answer (score 0):

You don't need jQuery for something like that, can be done with CSS.
"first" and "second" must be classes, not id's as id's must be unique.

```css
.second {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

.first {
  opacity: 1;
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="1" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="2" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="3" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
  <div id="4" class="hideme">
    <div class="first">A</div>
    <div class="second">B</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for. After the first simultaneous fade out, I want the first one to fade in, then the second one, then the third one, and finally the fourth one. All at different times but same interval lengths. And then have them all fade out simultaenously before the cycle begins again. Also, I would prefer to use jquery, because there's more to it than just what I wrote and putting it all in would be troublesome.